# How to get current datetime with format Y-m-d H:M:S using node-datetime library of nodejs?

Tags: node.js, datetime

I'm using [node-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-datetime/) library. I want to get current datetime with format such as Year-month-day hour-minute-second

ex : *2016-07-04 17:19:11*

```
var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
var dt = dateTime.create();
dt.format('m/d/Y H:M:S');
console.log(new Date(dt.now()));
```

But my result such as:

> Mon Jul 04 2016 17:19:11 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-datetime#methods) for details on `format`:

> Returns a formatted date time string.

Store the result of your call to `dt.format` and don't pass this to the `Date` constructor:

```
var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
var dt = dateTime.create();
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
console.log(formatted);
```

[ Run the example above: https://replit.com/@SamGluck1/so-node-datetime ]

I have amended the format string from `'m/d/Y'` to `'Y-m-d'` as per your question.

Comment: Awesome, but what about TImeZone? How can I change that?

Comment: I like moment - they have a specific timezone library as well. https://momentjs.com/timezone/ to get and format the current date/time `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`